# Example of a topology on R except usual topology, with exactly one limit point for each converging sequence

Tags: general-topology, limits

A convergent sequence in R has exactly one limit point, if R is under usual topology. Give an example of another topology on R with this property.

Comment: How about the discrete topology?

Comment: 1. Discrete topology; 2. Half-open interval topology.

Comment: Note that if the topology is first countable, then the condition on limits is equivalent to the topology also being Hausdorff.

Comment: Since $\mathbb R$ has the same cardinality as $[0,1]$ you can find a topology on $\mathbb R$ which is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$. But $[0,1]$ is metrizable (hence limits are unique,) and $[0,1]$ is compact, which the usual topology on $\mathbb R$ is not. So we get a non-homeomorphic topology.

Comment: Let $X=\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$, with $U\subseteq X$ open in $X$ if and only if it is open in $\mathbb R$. Find a bijection $\phi:\mathbb R\to X$. Then define a new topology on $\mathbb R$ as: $U$ is open if and only if $\phi(U)$ is open  in $X$. This topology on $\mathbb R$ is not path-connected, so it is not homemorphic to the usual topology.

Answer (score 1):

Given a topological space $(Y,\tau)$ and a bijective function $f:X\to Y$, we can define a topology $\tau_f$ on $X$ such that $f:X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism.
 Namely:

$$\tau_f=\{U\subseteq X\mid f(U)\in\tau\}$$

This is useful, because a lot of topological spaces have the same cardinality as $\mathbb R$.

Now, while it is not true for all topologies, all metric spaces have unique limits. So if we can find a metric space with cardinality equal to $\mathbb R$ which has properties different from $\mathbb R$, we are done.

All of the examples in comments above (other than the half-open intervals) are such metric spaces:

1. $[0,1]$ is a compact metric space with cardinality $\mathbb R$, so there is a topology on $\mathbb R$ which is compact. Since the usual topology on $\mathbb R$ is not compact, this new topology is not homeomorphic to the usual.
2. $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$ with the usual topology is not path-connected, and has the same cardinality as $\mathbb R$, so there is a topology on $\mathbb R$ which is not path-connected. $\mathbb R$ is path connected, so this new topology is not homeomorphic to the usual topology.
3. The discrete topology on any set $X$ is metrizable with $d(x,y)=0$ if $x=y$ and $d(x,y)=1$ if $x\neq y$. If $|X|=|\mathbb R|$, then this gives a discrete topology on $\mathbb R$.
4. If $X=\mathbb R^2$ with the standard topology, then $|X|=|\mathbb R|$ and we can see that $X$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$ with the standard topology because if we remove a point from $X$, it is still path-connected, but that is not true for $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology.

---

The half-open topology is interesting because it is a "bigger" topology than the standard topology. It has, as basis, the half-open intervals $[a,b)$, but it includes all standard open sets by seeing that $(a,b)=\bigcup_{n>0}[a+\frac{1}{n}+a,b)$. Limits are unique here from the more general result:

> Given a space $(X,\tau)$ with unique limits, and another topology $\tau'\supset \tau$ on $X$, we get that $(X,\tau')$ also has unique limits.

This is easy to prove. Essentially, if $x_n\to x$ in $(X,\tau')$ then $x_n\to x$ in $(X,\tau)$, but not necessarily visa versa. So adding to the open sets gives no additional convergences, but it can remove convergences.

For example, in the half-open topology, $x_n=\frac{-1}{n}$ doesn't converge, because $[0,1)$ is an open set containing $0$ which doesn't contain any $x_n$. But it can't converge to any other value because if $a\neq 0$ then the interval $(a-|a|/2,a+|a|/2)$ contains only finitely many $x_i$. Essentially, for each $a\neq 0$ we already have an open set $U\in\tau$ which is a "counterexample" showing that $x_n$ does not converge to $a$.

(In the half-open topology, a sequence $x_n\to x$ if and only if $x_n\to x$ in the usually topology *and* all but finitely many $x_i$ are greater than $x$.)

[This general result also proves the case of the discrete topology, again.]